# Running rake db:migrate gives "Could not find coffee-script-source-1.3.3 in any of the sources" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler

I just made a fresh Rails app (Rails v3.2.8) and tried running `rake db:migrate` with one migration, but I always get this error:

```
Could not find coffee-script-source-1.3.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

However, when I run `bundle install`, it indicates that coffee-script-source-1.3.3 is already installed:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
....
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Any ideas? If it helps, I am also running `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.1.0]`, which I installed via `brew install ruby`

Edit: I am not using rvm

Comment: does it make a difference if you run bundle exec rake db:migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the rake task is not being executed in the context of your current bundle (specified by your Gemfile). To ensure your task is running in the proper context, run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` instead.

Running executables via bundle exec is considered to be the safest route as it guarantees that only the gems at versions you expect (ie: what is declared in your Gemfile.lock) will be used.

Source: [bundle-exec man page](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html)